# Cannot view and edit order after install opencart on my server

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

Yesterday I install opencart on my server. After install I added some product and change country & zone. When customer completed their order I got an email notification but I can not view and edit order from admin panel. Please give me the solution.

Comment: It doesn't makes any sense , in admin/sale/order you should be able to edit the order

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred for hosting problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this particular issue. Once an order is created, I, the Admin, couldn't edit the order. It's not a bug or anything. It's a security update which opencart implemented via user/api, and is called during several operations on site, ie Order Additions, Deletions or Modifications.

For it to work for you, ask your host to disable mod_security for urls with "admin", or urls containing your IP Address, or check if your htaccess can overide and disable it from there.

You can also exclude per request/method type 'POST' or 'GET'.

Please note, Latest mod_sec is mod_security2

Guess am happy after I found out the real issue. 
[image]